# How to remove a zero frequency artefact from FFT using numpy.fft.fft() when detrending or subtracting the mean does not work

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to calculate the FFT of the following data : [data.txt](http://www.mediafire.com/file/91olqnm6i9qh5bl/data.txt/file)

```py
y_array = np.loadtxt('data.txt',dtype='complex')
plt.plot(np.real(y_array))
```

[image: Original Data]

```py
y_array_fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(y_array))
x_array = np.linspace(-125,125,len(y_array))
```

The FFT plot :

[image]

I want to remove the artefact at zero frequency which I think is the DC offset. For this, I tried subtracting the mean from the original signal and also use scipy.signal.detrend() for removing a linear trend from data before fft. However, both operations do not seem to have any effect on the FFT.

```py
y_array_detrend = signal.detrend(y_array)
y_array_mean_subtracted = y_array-np.mean(y_array)

y_array_detrend_fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(y_array_detrend))
y_array_mean_subtracted_fft  = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(y_array_mean_subtracted))
```

FFT after transforming the data using scipy.detrend():

[image: fft_after_detrend]

FFT after subtracting the mean from data :

[image: FFT after mean subtraction]

Any help or comments is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are asking a *maths* question. See if your question is [on topic over at SignalProcessing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/asking). It is probably a better fit there.  What does the fft look like for `np.real(y_array)[50:]`? Is the *artifact* due to that large transient at the very beginning of the data (the edge) with nothing before it for the fft to use? Maybe try padding the data.

Comment: The FFT still has the same feature (relatively bigger now) if do the FFT of ```np.real(y_array)[50:]```

Will have a look at the link you gave, Thanks!

Comment: Lots of good reading over there at [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract the mean, then what's left isn't a 0 Hz artifact, but some low frequency spectrum (perhaps between 2 to 10 Hz in your plot, depending on your dimensions).  Try a high pass filter.

Also, since it's complex data, make sure you subtracted the complex mean.